# UI Bootstrap modal in directive- multiple modals but only one opens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

As seen in [this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YYcU2fYp9iSxTAsPs41r?p=preview), I have two modals, each in separate directive of `modal-one` and `modal-two`.

The problem is, that only modal one is being opened, even when clicking on modal two button.

I guess that it has something to do with the `.open` method on the `$scope` is overwritten?

How do I prevent it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically behind the scene you are sharing a single scope amongest both the directive, as you don't have `scope` property inside directive, it sets to `false`(it will share up the scope). So when first directive gets loaded it registers `$scope.open` method with popup code. And when the other directive renders it takes same scope and override `$scope.open` method.

You could easily fix this issue by making your directive scope to use `scope: true` / `scope: {}`

[**Working Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZbaGwfeNB84tsLmDL9nU?p=preview)

Else you could share the same scope, but then you need to change the method name in one of two directive.

[**Other Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hUqTejafjeToiJJEdlc1?p=preview)